# Fitting Images Inside col-xs-6

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to fit the 4 images of the platform shoes inside each col-xs-6 box however they dont seem to be fitting.

Before I added the `<h4>` the col-xs-6 were overlapping the side of the page making the whole page off.

Any ideas on how I can fix this. I would like the `<h4>` to be over the boxes as well.

```
<div id="meettheband">
<h4> MEET THE BAND </h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 nobby">
      <img src="/Users/Reece/Desktop/SLYDE_RESPONSIVE/img/GLAMPLATFORMS.jpg" width="400" height="400" class="img-responsive">

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 dave">

      <img src="/Users/Reece/Desktop/SLYDE_RESPONSIVE/img/GLAMPLATFORMS.jpg" width="400" height="400" class="img-responsive">

    </div>

  </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 jammy">

      <img src="/Users/Reece/Desktop/SLYDE_RESPONSIVE/img/GLAMPLATFORMS.jpg" width="400" height="400" class="img-responsive">

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 dozy">

      <img src="/Users/Reece/Desktop/SLYDE_RESPONSIVE/img/GLAMPLATFORMS.jpg" width="400" height="400" class="img-responsive">

      </div>

  </div>

</div>

#meettheband {

   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   background-color: black;
   display: flex;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.nobby {
  border: solid red 1px;

}

.dave {
    border: solid red 1px;

}

.jammy {
    border: solid red 1px;

}

.dozy {
    border: solid red 1px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images have inline attributes specifying an explicit width - which is wider than the column width. So setting a maximum width to any image that ends up in these columns will circumvent this overlfow:

```
.col-xs-6 img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
#meettheband {

   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   background-color: black;
   display: flex;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.nobby {
  border: solid red 1px;

}

.dave {
    border: solid red 1px;

}

.jammy {
    border: solid red 1px;

}

.dozy {
    border: solid red 1px;

}

.col-xs-6 img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="meettheband">
<h4> MEET THE BAND </h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 nobby">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" width="400" height="400" class="img-responsive">

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 dave">

      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" width="400" height="400" class="img-responsive">

    </div>

  </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 jammy">

      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" width="400" height="400" class="img-responsive">

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 dozy">

      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=400%C3%97400&w=400&h=400" width="400" height="400" class="img-responsive">

      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

If you'd like to keep proportions relative, just add `height: auto` to the style rule in question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `width` or `height` of the images to take 100% of the container, e.g.:

```
.nobby img {
  width: 100%; /* or height:100% */
}
```

If you need to keep the inline sizes, i.e. `400px`, when the container is bigger than that:

```
.nobby img {
  max-width: 100%; /* or max-height:100% */
}
```

This will overwrite the inline width and height you set on the `img` element, when possible, otherwise it will take the full size of the container.

Another solution for keeping the size you set but keep the image from overfitting would be:

```
.nobby {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys that doesnt seem to work. The images have fit in okay I guess but the col-xs-3 seem to be took big for the images and they are still overlapping on the sides. Any more ideas. Heres a pastebin link? http://pastebin.com/iiMQ3PTv

Comment: @reecechapas, I think the issue is with `display: flex`, that breaks the Bootstrap styles